# Having trouble with H-15

Tags: haskell

I am doing [Problem 15](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/11_to_20). Which states:

```
(**) Replicate the elements of a list a given number of times.

    Example:

    * (repli '(a b c) 3)
    (A A A B B B C C C)

    Example in Haskell:

    > repli "abc" 3
    "aaabbbccc"
```

My plan was to do something like this:

```
repli :: [a] -> Integer -> [a]

repli [] y = []

repli (x:xs) y | appendNo x y == [] = repli(xs) y
               | otherwise = appendNo x y : (x:xs)
               where
               appendNo :: a -> Integer -> [a]
               appendNo a 0 = []
               appendNo a y = a:appendNo a (y-1)
```

Where I would make a function called appendNo that returns a list of 1 element y times then append it to the original list. Then take the body of the list and repeat this process until there are no more body elements left. But, I get the error:

```
H15.hs:6:30:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for repli :: [a] -> Integer -> [a] at H15.hs:3:1
    In the return type of a call of `appendNo'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `appendNo x y'
    In the expression: appendNo x y : (x : xs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

`6:30` is at the on the `p` in `appendNo` in this line:

```
           | otherwise = appendNo x y : (x:xs)
```

Ok thanks dave4420 I was able to figure it out by doing:

```
repli :: [a] -> Integer -> [a]

repli [] y = []

repli (x:xs) y = appendNo x y ++ repli(xs) y
               where
               appendNo :: a -> Integer -> [a]
               appendNo a 0 = []
               appendNo a y = a:appendNo a (y-1)
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to your type error, but consider breaking up this problem into parts and seeing if you have any tools to accomplish each of these parts.

There are 3 general parts to this solution:

1) doing something to each character

2) repeating a character N times

3) stringing those characters back together

Comment: Note that the `| appendNo x y == []` case is not needed. The other case works well enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
       | otherwise = appendNo x y : (x:xs)
```

There is a type error in this line. So ask yourself:

1. What is the type of `appendNo x y`?
2. What is the type of `(x:xs)`?
3. What is the type of `(:)`?

Then you should be able to see why they don't match up.

If you still can't see why they don't match up, ask yourself

1. What is the type of `x`?
2. What is the type of `xs`?
3. What is the type of `(:)`?

Bear in mind that this time the types *do* match up.

Comment: Ok, I have other errors now... But, doing `:t (:)` tells me I should switch the `(:)` to `(++)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the problem is solved, let me give you a hint: You should try to think in **transformations**, not in "loops". Start with some concrete values like n = 3 and list = "ABCD". Then you should think along the lines "I need every element three times". There is already a function for doing the replication, which is surprisingly called `replicate`. So the sentence can be translated to `map (replicate 3) "ABCD"`, which gives you `["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD"]`. That's almost what you want, you just need to `concat` the elements. This gives:

```
repli list n = concat (map (replicate n) list)
```

Because this operation is very common, there is a `concatMap` function combining `concat` and `map`, as well as the operator `(>>=)` doing the same, just with flipped arguments. So a very short solution would be:

```
repli list n = list >>= replicate n
```

This can be translated to the do-notation or a list comprehension as well:

```
repli list n = do
     x <- list
     y <- replicate n x
     return y  

repli list n = [y | x <- list, y <- replicate n x]
```